# Значение в базе увеличивается на 2 вместо 1

Tags: sql

На странице есть запрос `UPDATE таблица SET views=views+1 WHERE id LIKE '1'` который должен увеличивать значение на единицу. Но в результате значение увеличивается на 2. Почему так?

Comment: А почему like  вместо = ?

Comment: в примере было like.

Comment: Запрос написан верно (за исключением странного LIKE. можно, как указал pavel, просто использовать "=", что намного оптимальнее). Очевидно, он просто выполняется два раза. Либо он присутствует на странице два раза, либо та часть страницы, где он присутствует, выполняется дважды.Если сами не найдете проблему - покажите код страницы или пример. На данный момент данных недостаточно, чтобы ответить на вопрос.

Comment: Заменил на "=" также добавляется 2. Проверю код еще раз. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А триггера там нет?